# How to use DeclareMathOperator in MathJax configuration file?

Tags: mathjax

I would like to declare some math operators in my local Mathjax configuration file, so that I could use them in every page.

I find that I could define command as described in the MathJax documentation, [Defining TeX macros](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=declaremathoperator#defining-tex-macros).

But I couldn't find any reference to use `DeclareMathOperator` in a configuration file? Any workaround?

Comment: What have you tried? E.g., something like `Macros: { somehow: ["\\operatorname{somehow}"]    }` should work fine.

Comment: DeclareMathOperator does more than add an extra operatorname.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger http://mathb.in/13571

Comment: I'm aware of that but it wasn't very clear what you wanted from the information provided.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger i want to define an operator that works like one defined using DeclareMathOperator

Comment: @Unknown, your mathb.in example is using MathJax v2.3, which contained an error concerning how the starred forms were handled.  This was corrected in v2.4 (see the [issue tracker for it](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/739)), and if you use v2.4 or later, Peter's macro will give you the same result as `\DeclareMathOperator{\somehow}{somehow}`.  The starred forms should also work the same.  If you want to have TeX-based definitions, you might consider the [preamble](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions/tree/master/preamble) 3rd-party extension.

Comment: @DavideCervone, Thanks for your explanation. Indeed I don't have a computer 5 hours ago, so I just imagined that the result might be incorrect. And the link I found by google made me believe that I was right. But now I have got access to my computer and tested that just now, It works fine. Thank you for your comment and, more important, your effort to make such a wonderful tool!

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve what you want with the configuration below:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
        Macros: {
            sen: ["\\operatorname\{sen\}"],
            tg: ["\\operatorname\{tg\}"],
        },
    },
});
```